# Scout Eclipse AbstractGroupBox auto size

Tags: layout, eclipse-scout

I would like to have `AbstractGroupBox` that will grep all place that is available.

For Example :

if my form is like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  ------------      ------------       ------------      |
|  |some field|      |some field|       |some field|      |
|  ------------      ------------       ------------      |
|                                                         |
|  ------------------------------------------------------ |
| |                    AbstractGroupBox                 | |
|  ------------------------------------------------------ |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to have `AbstractGroupBox` to take all height of the form data.

I know I need to add

```
@Override
protected boolean getConfiguredGridUseUiHeight() {

  return false;
}
```

because it has no content. By default `Fill Vertical` is set to `true`. 
By what I can understand I should set

```
@Override
protected double getConfiguredGridWeightY() {

  return 1.0;
}
```

so grid cell will grep more space as Scout helps says.

But with all this set I still have small `AbstractGroupBox`.

How to set `AbstractGroupBox` that will grep all space available?

---

EDIT :

The layout is :

[image]

and my code is :

```
@Order(60.0)
public class ViewBox extends AbstractGroupBox {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredLabel() {

    return TEXTS.get("ViewBox");
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredBackgroundColor() {

    return "364BFF";
  }

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredGridW() {

    return 4;
  }

  @Override
  protected double getConfiguredGridWeightY() {

    return 1.0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to follow... This code works for me:

```
@Order(5000.0)
public class MyGroupBoxField extends AbstractGroupBox {

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredGridW() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  protected double getConfiguredGridWeightY() {
    return 1.0;
  }
}
```

Maybe I did not understood your use case, but this is what I get:

[image: Eclipse Scout Form (Swing UI)]

Comment: I add Edit with picture of my layout and code that I have.

Comment: Can you pleas check my code in my edit and see if there is something that I miss.

Comment: I have seen your edit a long time ago. From what I see I can not tell what is wrong in your case. My example works.